# What's the best way of drawing a glowing 3d line using LWJGL?

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl

Sort of like a strip-light effect; not actually a light source, but just a polygon with glowing edges.

Can this be done easily? Right now I'm contemplating drawing a line more than once with varying alpha/width values to achieve this, but I think that'll cause weird glowing points at the vertices, which is far from ideal.

Comment: Chances are you will want a shader.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to extrude the line into a polygon, but do it like you'd billboard a point sprite (but for a line segment).